# Hypothesis testing for binomial distribution: a simple real-life case

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

I'm refreshing (or maybe just acquiring) some stats skills, and I have a real-life situation, probably very simple since it's quite close to a typical example from stats courses, that I would like to check for errors in my reasoning (since I couldn't match it exactly to an existing example). I hope it's OK to ask here if I got it right or I'm doing something wrong.

**The problem**

There is an automated process that results in a success in 61% of cases. That percentage is empirical but based on a huge amount of data so I'm just assuming it to be the true population mean for simplification. There is a new process that I could implement, but its implementation will cost time & resources, so I don't want to do it and find out it's actually not better. There's reasons to believe it could have a success rate of around 75%, although that is rather arbitrary. I would be happy if I could be sure it will improve my success rate by 5 points at least.

I'm wondering whether I should make a series of manual tests of this process, which is not for free but might help me confirm or discard the implementation of the automated process and increase my confidence that I am engaging a whole team in a useless effort. So I'm trying to determine here what I would need to get high confidence that the new process is better (by at least 5 points) and how likely it is that I can actually obtain what I need and reach such a conclusion. I could afford to do something in the order of magnitude of 10-20 manual tests.

**Part 1: what would make me conclude the new process is better**

My null hypothesis is: new process has a success rate p=66% or less 
My alternate hypothesis is: new process has a success rate p>66%
This is how I make sure that I get a difference of 5 points at least, right?

I'm setting alpha at 0,10 -- I don't need perfect certainty, just a strong enough indicator.
My number of manual tests is currently set at n=20.

To be 90% sure my new process is above 66%, I need to have BINOM.INV(20, .66, .90) successes among the 20 trials (in R that would be the qbinom function I think), giving me 16 or 80%.

**Part 2: same as part 1 with t-distribution**

This is just because as I was struggling to understand what my variable was etc., I was considering the t-distribution. I then realized that (I think!) I can use it too to approximate the binomial one in this case, though it's not simpler at all. But I can calculate the standard error of a 20-trial sample as se = P(1-P)/sqrt(n), in this case .61*(1-.61)/sqrt(20)=0.10906. Note that I used P=0.61 my assumed true population mean and not the one from my hypothesis, I'm confused as to whether this is correct or not.
I also need the t-quantile T.INV(1-alpha, n-1) which is 1.3277 and then I calculate the percentage of successed needed as .66+ 1.3277 * 0.10906 = 80%. For various values of n this matches more or less, the mismatches being probably due to the binomial distribution returning discrete values.
Is this t-approach correct?

**Part 3: is it worth trying it?**

So now I'm thinking, with that sample size and alpha I need 80% of successes to be sure that I'm at 66% or above. How likely is that to happen? I imagine I need to take an assumption of the true mean of the new process. If I take the same value 66% then by definition I'm saying that I have 10% (alpha)  of probability that this happens. If my arbitrarily hoped-for success rate is 75%, then I have BINOM.DIST(16,20,.75,TRUE) (in R that would be the pbinom function I think). That gives me 22%.

=> Do I get this right? Is my conclusion that it's pretty much useless to do a test with 20 trials (or 30 or 50 for that matter, it increases the chances but not by a lot), because it's unlikely I will get to significant results if the new process has a 75% success rate?

=> Have I just calculated  the power of the test, or is this totally unrelated? (I'm struggling with that concept in practice)

**Other questions**

Out of curiosity, what if my initial percentage was not the true population mean but I wanted to consider it a reference sample instead? How would I do the 2-sample comparison with a binomial distribution? How would I assess whether it's worth to make a manual sample or not in that case?